# How can I rea a specific column in a CSV file using java?

Tags: java, csv, file, arraylist, io

I have a CSV file (as shown), how can I read a specific column (for example: age) using java and store it's values **only without the header** in an `ArrayList` ?
I do not want to use any dependencies Like OpenCSV or other:

| age | data | numbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 3434 | 2343 |
|  | 3444 |  |
| 2232 |  |  |
| 32332 |  |  |

Comment: Use a CSV parser. Unless this is a homework exercise - in which case you will learn more from doing than asking - just use a CSV parser. No one is paying you to invent square wheels.

Comment: Assuming homework:  You'll need a CSV file for input, and you'll need to first figure out how to read all columns from the CSV file.  After that the solution will be much easier to synthesize.

Comment: Your best bet is to use a library ... like OpenCSV.  If you don't want to do that, it's trivial to a) open your file (e.g. using a [BufferedReader](https://www.journaldev.com/709/java-read-file-line-by-line), b) read it a line at a time, c) discard the first line, d) String.split() on "," to parse the line into columns, and e) add the column you want to save into your ArrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically a simple, elegant one liner

```
Files.readAllLines(Path.of("/path/to/your.csv")).stream().skip(1) //skip header
  .map(l -> l.split(";")[0]) // get first column i.e. age
  .collect(Collectors.toList()); // and get it as List
```

Answer (score 2):

this should do the job if you want to use the default format you can use ';' as a column separator.

```
public static List<String> readOnlyOneColumn(String pathToCsv,String columnSeparator,int columnIndex)
  throws IOException 
{
return Files.lines(Paths.get(pathToCsv)).skip(1).map(e -> e.split(columnSeparator)).map(columns -> columns[columnIndex]).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check our `csv` file format, exists a lot of custom formats.

```
"String Header";"Numeric Header"
"this is a string value";154566.52
```

```
String Header;Numeric Header
this is a string value;154566.52
```

```
String Header\tNumeric Header
this is a string value\t154566.52
```

```java
Files.readAllLines(Path.of("/path/to/your.csv")).stream().skip(1) //skip header
  .map(l -> l.split(";")[0]) // get first column i.e. age
  .collect(Collectors.toList()); // and get it as List
```

```java
BufferedReader reader = BufferedReader(new FileInputStreamReader("/path/to/your.csv"));
reader.readLine();
valuesArr = new ArrayList();
while(reader.ready()) {
     String line = reader.readLine();
     valuesArr.add(line.split(";")[0]);
}
```

this 2 ways will output respectively results on :

```
["\"this is a string value\""]
["this is a string value"]
["this is a string value\t154566.52"]
```

Comment: This will work for the input given, but doesn't work on CSV files in general.  CSV entries can be quoted, in which case the processing is different.

Comment: Yeah, it's correct, but for this cases the developer must inspect the CSV file to skip " ' characters